With LSP, how to quickly find the definition of non-<cword>
In neovim with LSP support, it can quickly go to the definition of <cword> with lsp definition. But it cannot find the definition with a query. I have the requirements below. Currently, I rely on LSP workspace_symbol. It can list several similar functions, but cannot directly go to the definition. Is there any better solution?
The cursor is on a function, such as create_post(). And there is a related function named p_create_post(). I want to go to the definition of p_create_post() from create_post().
